# using path parameters in nestjs guard

Tags: javascript, nestjs

Can I get path parameters in NestJS guard function using some other way than just looking for a raw request object from http context?

What I want to do for example is

```js
@Patch(':id/someActionName')
@UseGuards(SomeGuard)
async activateRole(@Param('id') id, @Body() input: SomeObject): Promise < any > {
    //some logic
    return response;
}
```

And my `SomeGuard` would get value of 'id' parameter and 'input' parameter, input parameter is easy, but I don't see easy way to get 'id'

Answer (score 33):

In your guard you can access the route parameters by getting the request from the context like so:

```
canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
  const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
  const params = request.params;
  const id = params.id; // automatically parsed
}
```

This wasn't in the documentation and I had the exact same problem as you and had to dig through the request object.

Be aware of, `Guards are executed after all middleware, but before any interceptor or pipe.` https://docs.nestjs.com/guards

Comment: Thanks, find out also about order of validation and guards, so in my use case it's unusable, because validation pipe is working after the guards so i could not perform some checks in the guards. Or I will have to perform them twice in guard and in validation.